# Know part of a URL

Tags: google-search

I know part of a URL, is there any way to search for URLs that contain at least the part of the URL I know?

I know this is not a "programming question" exactly, but I feel this occasionally happens to others. I wrote down a URL during a seminar, and most of it is legible (and the words make sense), but a few parts are uncertain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a pretty simple solution.

In Google search, you would use their advanced search parameter - inurl.

```
inurl:"product"
```

Surrounding the search term in quotes will ensure the whole word is there.